# Flutter - Parse Json with parent set

Tags: json, list, visual-studio, flutter, dart

I can parse in my code json file like below. It works fine:

```
[
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952",
      "publishDate": "2021-03-12"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796",
      "publishDate": "2021-03-12"
  }
]
```

but i need to update my json file to be able to present data from a specific parent. In this example: position1 or position 2.

```
{
  "position1":[
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952",
      "publishDate": "2021-03-12"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796",
      "publishDate": "2021-03-12"
  }
],
  "position2":[
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952",
      "publishDate": "2021-03-12"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796",
      "publishDate": "2021-03-12"
  }
]
}
```

My code looks like below. What should I do to list only children items from ex: position1.

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client
      .get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'));
     
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Photo>((json) => Photo.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

and

```
body: FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
    future: fetchPhotos(http.Client()),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

      return snapshot.hasData
          ? PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data!)
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    },
  ),
```